# Start-Stop timer via same Button

Tags: java, swing, timer, awt

I try start-stop timer via same Jbutton. Let me share my code;

Button Action;

```
private void ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

        if(Button.getText().equals("START")){
        Button.setText("STOP");
        Spinner.setEnabled(false);
        Informer.setBackground(Color.green);
        Informer.setText("Running");
        Timer time = new Timer();
        ScheduledTask st = new ScheduledTask();
        time.schedule(st, 0, (int) Spinner.getValue()*1000*60);
        }
        else{
        Button.setText("START");
        Spinner.setEnabled(true);
        Informer.setBackground(Color.red);
        Informer.setText("Stopped");

        }

    }
```

When user press the button; Button name changed STOP from START,
Named informer textfield paint to green and write in Running,
And below timer started,

```
public class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {
        if (Button.getText().equals("STOP")){
                   Worker1 worker1 = new Worker1();
                   worker1.execute();
                }
                else{
                ScheduledTask.this.cancel();
                }
    }
}
```

As you can see timer execute a SwingWorker named worker1. If i press button again (named STOP) jbutton renamed to START and timer dont see STOP in button text than stop itself.

Imagine setup the timer 1 min and press the START button. When START button pressed worker1 executed immediatelly and timer start countdown you know. In 20-30 sec press the STOP button and wait 5-10 sec. Press the START button again. Problem is here 2 timer already running now. When first timer countdown complete worker1 executed. 5-10 seconds later timer fininsh old countdown and start worker1 again.

How can i stop current timer countdown when same button pressed if any countdown already active?

Comment: Don't use a `TimerTask` here. Instead implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 0):

you can use two different buttons at the same place. 
At first when the start button is pressed the timer will start and the button will go hide and  the stop button will come up and vice versa.

Comment: I can use this method instead one button thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The probmen isn't in the swing JButtons at all.

The problem is that you are not cancelling the worker tasks properly. Here:

```
    if (Button.getText().equals("STOP")){
               Worker1 worker1 = new Worker1();
               worker1.execute();
    }
    else{
            ScheduledTask.this.cancel();
    }
```

You have no guarantee that the button will have text "STOP" when the timer is done.

You need to stop the Timer itself when you press the stop button, to prevent starting your scheduled task in the first place.

Comment: Exactly you are right. But if i use same button for start-stop action i must use if condition inside ButtonAction you know. How i stop current timer outside if clause ?

Comment: Yes, you will neet to use if condition. Stopping timer inside if condition is perfectly fine, if you are asking how to stop timer, check first three resluts on googling "java cancel timer"

Comment: But time variable is not recognised under else condition in my buton action code. So how can i stop currently activated TimerTask when press same button ?

Comment: That is because a thing called `scope`: you need to define your timer outside any method - in your class - and make it a field variable, that way, it will be accessible from all methods.